# Playwright selecting element with text= or hastext with exact match

Tags: playwright

I'm using playwright nodejs. I've written myself a little dynamic selector function to select the page number button on a dataTable.

```
pageNumberButton(page, table_id, page_number) {
   page.locator(`[aria-controls=${table_id}]`, {hasText: page_number});
}
```

I've also tried:

```
pageNumberButton(page, table_id, page_number) {
   page.locator(`[aria-controls=${table_id}] text=${page_number}`);
}
```

However, I can't seem to make it do an exact match.

Suppose my dataTable has 13 pages:

[image: dataTable button controls showing Previous, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., 13, Next button]

and I wish to click on page 1. so I issue the following command: `await pageNumberButton(page, "resultsTable", "1").click();`

But I get a strict-mode error, since there are two results: 1 and 13.

What would be the best, or good, way to create this little selector dynamically so that I can do an exact match for the button?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

text body can be escaped with single or double quotes to search for a text node with exact content

```
    pageNumberButton(page, table_id, page_number) {
       page.locator(`[aria-controls=${table_id}]`)
           .filter({ has: page.locator(`text="${page_number}"`) });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for providing an option that allows matching both the CSS selector and the exact text!

Comment: Great find on the quotes, but the `.filter()` isn't necessary here. You can [chain the text locator directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75553716/6243352). It's also a good idea to use quotes on the `aria-controls=` selector too. This should also `return` the locator.

Answer (score 10):

I found an option. Create a regex object and pass that in for hasText.

```
pageNumberButton(page, table_id, page_number) { 
    const regexNumber = new RegExp(`^${page_number}$`); 
    page.locator(`[aria-controls=${table_id}]`, {hasText: regexNumber});
}`
```

Answer (score 5):

Exact matching is possible with `{exact: true}`. See this example from the [docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/locators#locate-by-text):

```js
await expect(page.getByText('Welcome, John', { exact: true })).toBeVisible();
```

Note that this *does* normalize whitespace, which is probably the desired behavior in most cases, so it's not quite "exact" as advertised.

Applied to your case:

```js
page
  .locator(`[aria-controls="${tableId}"]`)
  .getByText(pageNumber, {exact: true});
```

---

It's possible to use the `text=` syntax in the locator as you've attempted, as long as you separate the CSS and `text=` locators into two calls and use quotes inside the `text=""` selector. Applied to your example:

```js
page
  .locator(`[aria-controls="${table_id}"]`)
  .locator(`text="${page_number}"`);
```

Here's a complete, runnable demonstration:

```js
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.39.0

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<div aria-controls="foo">1</div>
<div aria-controls="foo">13</div>
</body>
</html>`;

const pageNumberButton = (page, tableId, pageNumber) => {
  return page
    .locator(`[aria-controls="${tableId}"]`)
    .locator(`text="${pageNumber}"`);
};

test("aria-controls='foo' with text '1' is visible", async ({page}) => {
  await page.setContent(html);
  await expect(pageNumberButton(page, "foo", 1)).toBeVisible();
});
```

Forgetting quotes in the `text=""` syntax is a subtle gotcha, which is why I prefer the more explicit `getByText("...", {exact: true})`.

Use quotes on the `[aria-controls="..."]` CSS selector as well as the `text=""` selector.

Don't forget to `return` the locator from your `pageNumberButton` function.

---

Yet another approach is the `:text-is("")` pseudoselector which "matches the smallest element with exact text. Exact matching is case-sensitive, trims whitespace and searches for the full string" according to [the docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/other-locators#css-matching-by-text):

```js
page.locator(`[aria-controls="${tableId}"]:text-is("${pageNumber}")`);
```

---

Further remarks:

- [Regex is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72007924/6243352), but I'd avoid this if possible because it's easy to forget that regex special characters like `.` are treated differently and wind up with subtle bugs.
- Generally, [`.filter()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73216189/6243352) should be avoided when possible. The syntax is less clear than a single chain of locators.
- CSS attributes aren't considered best practice in tests, so you may consider using a [test id](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-selectors#selectors-set-test-id-attribute) or, better, locating based on [user-visible](https://playwright.dev/docs/best-practices#test-user-visible-behavior) attributes.

Comment: It doesn't solve the actual problem. The element must be found by both the CSS select _and_ the exact text.

Comment: @AdamA Good point, but OP never showed their markup structure. It's a likely XY problem, because Playwright suggests avoiding CSS selectors in favor of user-visible attributes. `getByRole` may be appropriate here. Without sufficient context, this is intended as a supplement to the existing (already very good) answers for future reference, since the question is the canonical for "selecting by text" in Playwright. That said, one could use `getByText` as a drop-in with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73216189/6243352). As an aside, OP should also return their promise from the function.

Comment: It's not an XY problem - you are looking for an element with "1" on the page uniquely. "1" is likely not unique on the page in an element. All it takes is a second pagination control, for example, and now there are two. The aria-controls refinement is a good way to restrict this and keep the selector unique.

I added an answer that is "more simple, effective & straightforward" and actually solves the OP's problem. Your answer should exist, but "hence should be the accepted answer", which is strangely upvoted 5 times when the answer does not solve the original problem well, is wrong.

Comment: @AdamA The answer should be fully comprehensive at this point.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend `text-is` instead of `hasText`.

https://playwright.dev/docs/other-locators

Answer (score 2):

Playwright allows chaining locators. You can make a locator that solves your issue and also is simple and readable - no regex required. First you find the `aria-controls` element, then you find the correct button inside it:

```js
function pageNumberButton(page, table_id, page_number) {
   return page.locator(`[aria-controls=${table_id}]`)
       .getByText(`${page_number}`, { exact: true });
}
```

```js
await pageNumberButton(page, "resultsTable", "1").click();
```

should work fine after that.